# GLES2.0 glUnifrom2f and glUniform4f

Tags: opengl-es

why glUniform2f(xxx, x, y) behave different from glUniform4f(xxx, x, y, 0, 1);
Isn't z=0, w=1 the default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [OpenGL ES 2.0 reference for glUniform](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml) says:

> The number specified in the command should match the number of
>   components in the data type of the specified uniform variable (e.g., 1
>   for float, int, bool; 2 for vec2, ivec2, bvec2, etc.).

There's also no mention of defaults. What you're experiencing is probably undefined behavior - the results may be different on different drivers, driver versions, platforms, etc.